# How to detect camera existence with `AVFoundation`?

Tags: ios, camera, detection

Now iOS devices has 0~2 cameras. How to detect them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - How can I detect if the iPhone has a front camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629030/iphone-how-can-i-detect-if-the-iphone-has-a-front-camera)

Comment: @jeffamaphone Well... mine's March'11, and that's April'11. Can I know basis of marking duplication?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You iterate through the video devices...

```
NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices) {
    if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        //FRONT-FACING CAMERA EXISTS
    }
}
```

Of course you could also do this a bit quicker with a predicate, but i'll leave that for you to work out ;).... (HINT: use the filteredArrayUsingPredicate: method on the devicesWithMediaType:)

Comment: If you want to check for existence of ANY camera then you can use a UIImagePickerViewController and check the sourceTypeAvailable.

Comment: hey though the above code is working but below code is crashing             if ( position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront )
                newCamera = [ self cameraWithPosition : AVCaptureDevicePositionBack ] ;
            else{
                newCamera = [ self cameraWithPosition : AVCaptureDevicePositionFront ] ; 
                newInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:newCamera Error:nil];
            }
Any idea?