# iPhone - Detecting if the iDevice has a front camera

Tags: iphone, camera

Apple recommends not searching for hardware version, but for the specific feature in which you are interested.

So how may I detect if there is a front camera on the device to be able to disable some features ?

`[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]` only tells that there is a camera somewhere.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this method of UIImagePickerController:

`+ (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)cameraDevice`

This is a class method and UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice can take two values:

- `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear`
- `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront`

Example code:

```
if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
{
   // do something
}
```

Note that this is available for iOS 4.0 and later.

Comment: Uhhhh, ok, but if this is only available for iOS 4 and later, that may be stupid but how may I detect what king of camera is available if my user in on a 3G with iOS 3, without asking for the hardware ?

Comment: use [`isSourceTypeAvailable:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW2). If the device runs iOS3 there is only one camera.

Comment: `[UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(isCameraDeviceAvailable:)]` of course.

Comment: @Oliver: For devices that use iOS < 4.0 you can directly use the camera as there is only one if you are developing for iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift

```
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front
```

Comment: That sets the cameraDevice, but don't you need to check with `isCameraDeviceAvailable(_:)` first?