# ipad 2 camera support detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, camera

I have an app that uses the following Macro:

`#define IS_IPAD ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] && [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`

which works very well for me.

However, I was using it to turn off the option of taking a photo in the app.

How can I detect if the camera option is available regardless of device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

That should work

Answer (score 2):

See [How to Detect Camera Existence with AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350079/how-to-detect-camera-existence-with-avfoundation/5350195#5350195).

```
NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

if ( [videoDevices count] > 0 ) // This device has one or more cameras
....
```

Comment: Thanks Julio, what would this have over Joshua's answer?

Comment: Joshua's snippet is simpler, unless you need extended information on each individual camera, his answer should suffice.

Comment: Mine will also work on 3.x, but that isn't very important these days