# How can we know is Camera available or not in iPad

Tags: ipad, ios4, camera

I am implementing an iPad application, and I need to get pictures from the library and camera as well. My problem is the first version of iPad doesn't have the camera in built. How can I determine if camera is available or not? Can you guys please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ipad 2 camera support detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863328/ipad-2-camera-support-detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good start: [[UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isCameraDeviceAvailable%3a)]